# How expensive is using MarshalByRefObject compared to serialization?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, serialization, marshalling

In my Azure web role code I have a `CustomIdentity` class derived from `System.Security.Principal.IIdentity`. At some point .NET runtime [tries to serialize that class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6492762/57428) and [serialization wouldn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6493371/57428). Trying to resolve that I searched a lot and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884030/implementing-a-custom-identity-and-iprincipal-in-mvc/3214178#3214178) and tried to inherit my class from [`MarshalByRefObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4295894/57428).

Now once my `CustomIdentity` class inherits from `MarshalByRefObject` there're no serialization attempts anymore and my code works. However I'd like to know the performance implications of using `MarshalByRefObject` class.

My code runs like this. First the request comes to IIS and is passed to the authentication code that creates an instance of `CustomIdentity` and attaches that instance to HTTP context. Then some time later the same HTTP context is passed to the ASP.NET handler that accesses that `CustomIdentity` instance at most once. The `CustomIdentity` object lives for the duration of request and is then destroyed.

Now with serialization my `CustomIdentity` would be serialized into a stream, then deserialized from that stream into a new object. With `MarshalByRefObject` there's no serialization but a proxy is created and the access will be marshaled via RPC to where the actual object resides.

How expensive will using `MarshalByRefObject` be in this scenario? Which - `MarshalByRefObject` or serialization - will be more costly?

Comment: Depends on the transport. Using named pipes will likely have very little impact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`MarshalByRefObject` means that all *calls* (methods, properties, etc) are proxied over the wire. This potentially means that instead of transferring the data *once* and then running multiple methods etc locally on the transferred data, you are making a network call *every access*. How many times (per request) is a role tested, for example? or the name queried? I honestly don't know, but I'm guessing it is more than 1 (all totalled). Plus the original setup costs...

The bandwidth probably won't be significant, but latency ***is very*** significant, especially if you have distributed nodes (since you mention a cloud scenario).

Personally, I would avoid `MarshalByRefObject` like the plague, but up to you...

Comment: As a side note - in my scenario the "creator" code and the "consumer" code are always on the same machine and maybe even in the same process. It's not that one node runs the "creator" code and another one runs the "consumer" code.

Comment: I guess I'll have to profile that code and make a careful decision.

Comment: @sharptooth - are they in different AppDomains, then? if not...  just *why*?

Comment: @sharptooth I would focus my attention on *why does it want to serialize*, etc

Comment: Well, looks like the "creator" code is run when request is not yet authenticated and so is untrusted and the "consumer" code is run when the request is already authenticated and so is trusted and so they run in different app domains. The problem is my knowledge of app domains is very limited, so I'd rather address it sometimes later and for now I just patched the problem and am curious of how costly the patch is.

Comment: @sharptooth in the context of an in-process marshal, it probably isn't *too* terrible - but would need profiling.